# CSS dropdown menu with checkbox hack

Tags: css, checkbox

I am no expert in CSS, and I can't for the life of me get the checked option to display a div. In my head this should work, but it doesn't. Any help would be greatly appreciated. I think the problem is with this line of code.

```
.mobile-trigger:checked ~ .drop {
display: block;
}
```

[Example](https://jsfiddle.net/77c23ceq/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to hide content by default and once input is checked `display: block` will show it. Please note that general sibling combinator `~` *"separates two selectors and matches the second element only if it is preceded by the first, and both share a common parent"* so the element that has to be shown has to be a sibling after the checkbox.

```css
.drop {
  display: none;
}
.mobile-trigger:checked ~ .drop {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" class="mobile-trigger">
<div class="drop">test</div>
```

Reference: [MDN - General sibling selectors](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/General_sibling_selectors)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I followed what you did and built it back up from there. I think my error was in having the input below the div.